# validation of multiple input laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have multiple inputs and can I can add more by clicking on the button (+) to clone a div anywhere.

I need it so that when I save the form and the data is empty redirect back with all of the divs and inputs.
e.g: add five inputs, and when click submit and redirect I need show this inputs (five inputs).

**This is my sample code:**

```
<form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right" id="m_form_1" method="post">
    <div class="m-portlet__body">
        @if(is_array(old('name')) && count(old('name')) > 0)
            <div id="countriesContainer">
                @foreach(old('name') as $key => $item)
                    <div class="form-group m-form__group row countries">
                        <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">{{ trans('general.language') }}</label>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="language[]">
                                <option value="">{{ trans('general.select_item') }}</option>
                                @foreach($language as $row)
                                    <option value="{{ $row->locale }}" {{ old('language')[$item] == $row->locale ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $row->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type='text' class="form-control m-input lang" name="name" value="{{ old('name')[$item] }}" placeholder="{{ trans('countries.name') }}"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-brand m-btn m-btn--custom add">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger m-btn m-btn--custom remove">
                                <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @else
            <div id="countriesContainer">
                <div class="form-group m-form__group row countries">
                    <label class="col-form-label col-lg-2">{{ trans('general.language') }}</label>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <select class="form-control m-bootstrap-select m_selectpicker" data-live-search="true" name="language">
                            <option value="">{{ trans('general.select_item') }}</option>
                            @foreach($language as $row)
                                <option value="{{ $row->locale }}" {{ old('language') == $row->locale ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $row->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <input type='text' class="form-control m-input lang" name="name" placeholder="{{ trans('countries.name') }}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-brand m-btn m-btn--custom add">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger m-btn m-btn--custom remove">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</form>
```

**and here is my controller code:**

```
$language = $request->get('language');
$name = $request->get('name');
$status = (int)$request->get('status');
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "name.*"  => "required",
]);
```

Comment: so you are looking to use the {{ old(' ') }} but for multiple inputs?

Comment: iam use old, but not working when return redirect the input all div is not show just one input.

Comment: i've made an edit to your original post, and understand, I am currently working on the same problem right now - hopefully either someone can answer us first or I will find a solution

Answer (score 0):

`<input name="name" ...` should be `<input name="name[]" ...` if multiple input fields exists with same name it should be an array.

for receiving old value you need  [loop index](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) . not the `$item`

so ith should be

```
<input name="name[]" value="{{ old('name')[$loop->index] }}" ...
```

Comment: I don this, but when redirect input not return return one input just. i need when i add 3 or 5 or ..etc and click submit return the same input with error message validations.